# Is there a way to see how many unhelpful flags I have raised?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I've raised quite a number of flags on this site (averaging one about every couple of days) and I can see my "helpful flag" count and see the helpful flags I have raised. However, in order to get better at realising when raising a flag is appropriate, I'd like to see when I have raised unhelpful flags - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can see them on your [your flag history page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/15517) on the right hand side: it will show counts for disputed or declined flags if you had any. 
[See a snapshot of the flag history page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhRvU.png) The decline stats are listed with the other stats on the right sidebar of the page.

Incidentally it's quite normal to have a few declined or disputed flags. If you do get some don't panic! It just means somebody disagreed with your judgment call, which is to be expected now and then. Flags marked disputed are ones were other community members saw had been flagged in a review queue and "counter flagged" (flag to say no action required) and you don't get to know who (except that they have to have > 10k rep to even see that flag queue) or why. In the case of declined flags moderators will usually leave you a specific reason why they decided the flag was not valid. Reviewing these reasons and keeping them in mind for future similar situations is all you need to do.

For reference, even some of our BEST flaggers have ~ 5% decline rates.

Comment: "That count appears as a number in red parenthesis right next to your flag count" I suspect that might be a mod thing, because I've never seen it!

Comment: @curiousdannii Not ever on [your own profile](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/6071/curiousdannii)? I'll take that out of this answer and just leave the bit about the history page if that turn out to be a mod-view-only thing.

Comment: This is what I see: http://imgur.com/uhibXa9

Comment: @curiousdannii By the way your flag record is pretty epic. Going for double Marshal badges? Somebody should just give you an honorary diamond already, you already do half the hard work around here, we just sign off on it!

Comment: It slowed down considerably once I reached 3k and could just directly vtc. But I'll get to 1k flags eventually. I'm hoping to get Copy Editor soon!